# Automating folder permissions on SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

We have over 3000 folders in a document library. I would like to automate setting permissions by using a SharePoint list contains who can get access to folders.

When I change or add a new entry to my list, folder permission should be updated.  I have 100,000 documents with no metadata that I can use. Are any other approaches?

Comment: What is the question here? "other approaches" to what? Generally I feel what you're trying to do is "wrong", but you have not told what you are really trying to do with the list-folder-combination...

Comment: It sounds like a really bad approach is my feeling - you need to divide up the documents into separate document libraries in order to manage the files in a better way

Comment: I agree, Creating folders in the document library is not recommended. but how can I manage over 100000  documents permission if I get rid of folders? The question is, how can I automate Permissions while my documents do not have metadata. @Nils

Comment: Maybe you should explain the problem a bit more, so people can think about possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out these two articles on permission scope limits, I have a feeling you might hit these if you implement this kind of solution.  With that many folders you should look into moving some folders into their own document library.  Not to mention you are going to run into view limit issues unless you have setup column indexing and really good filtered views.  As for a solution you would need to write a workflow that runs on item creation / modification on the "permissions list" that then updates the permissions on the correct folder in the document library.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/best-practices-for-using-fine-grained-permissions-in-sharepoint-server

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Josh's answer.  Here are some links for you to read through, it's quite a big task that you have ahead of you to organise the documents into a good structure.  I almost question why they are using Sharepoint if they just want a simple file server structure!

One thing to consider is the lifespan of these documents, how are they going to be managed?  Data generally increases, server space will be diminished over time.

Security is another difficulty in managing your files in their current state.

I would recommend reading through some articles on Information Architecture, [you could start here](https://sharepointmaven.com/category/information-architecture/).